# File sizes greyed out (strange extended attributes) in Finder on Lion?

Tags: macos, finder, folders, uti

I just got a new machine with Lion preinstalled. After transferring all my applications, I noticed that the file sizes (and only the sizes) of some applications and folders are greyed out:

[image: example for greyed out files]

Does anybody know what this means?

**Update:**

`ls -la` gives the following lines for DjView and Dropbox:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 daniel  staff    102 31 Okt  2007 DjView.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 daniel  staff    102  3 Mai 10:06 Dropbox.app
```

I.e. Dropbox.app has extended file attributes, namely

```
$ xattr -p com.apple.FinderInfo Dropbox.app/
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Cheers

MrMage

Comment: Very interesting! I'm not seeing the same thing on my system.

Comment: Have you run a fix permissions after the migration? You shouldn't have to but that might be the reason.

Comment: Guess: The greyed out apps are PowerPC (and won't work under Lion)?

Comment: MrMage: Dropbox.app on my system has exactly the same extended attributes, and no grey size. So I don't think that can be the issue. An odd one, this.

Comment: You are right. There also are grey files _without_ extended attributes.

Comment: Do you see this in all user accounts?

Comment: There's just this one.

Comment: By the way, I'm using TotalFinder (but this behavior persists when I disable TotalFinder).

Comment: If you don't see it in other user accounts I wouldn't worry about it too much. It is probably due to some odd configuration setting.

Comment: I saw it temporarily with plenty of applications in `/Applications`, but eventually, all sizes became black. I've also checked whether this is related to HFS+ compression; that is *not* the case. Are we sure this doesn't simply mean that Finder is still busy calculating the size?

Comment: As long as it's calculating it doesn't show any size. Also, that calculation should be done almost immediately as the files are placed on a SSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have only the craziest of guesses, but since we're all striking out so far, here goes.

Is there any chance you've turned on the [Asepsis](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/asepsis) mode which installs a kernel extension? You may have not disabled that in your testing (a safe boot should confirm / rule this out as well). It seems possible that it's intentionally showing you which folders it has replaced the normal `.DS_store` file with entries in `/usr/local/.dscache`

I would also use `mdls` to inspect the metadata for these folders (since apps are really folders these days) in case some clue jumps out at you.

Comment: I indeed have Asepsis enabled, and simply deleting the (still-present) .DS_Store in the Applications folder removed all the gray sizes. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that those Apps are only sym links. Maybe those apps are in your ~/Applications folder, and are linked to the /Applications one.

Could you check it.

Edited to reflect the edit of the author.

Comment: These are good suggestions for starting to get to the bottom of this odd problem.

Comment: Updated the original post with the information you requested.

Comment: They aren't. In fact, they are located on /SSD/Applications (which is not the system partition), but the same gray text appears next to some applications in the /Applications folder.

Comment: Have you tried to re-download the greyed out apps which resides in the /Applications folder?

Comment: There are even some Apple applications affected. As it seems, they have the special attributes mentioned above, but I don't know what they mean.

Comment: Can you post the output of `file Dropbox.app`?

Comment: Hey, any luck with the output of `file Dropbox.app`?

Comment: Sorry, your comments weren't shown to me. The result is just `Dropbox.app/: directory`. I think the output of `xattr` (see original post) is more relevant in this case.

Comment: The size of my Dropbox app is not greyed out but still     `> xattr -p com.apple.FinderInfo Dropbox.app/
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` Sorry for the mess, I don't know how to insert a CR in the comments. However they look exactly like yours.

Comment: Moreover: ls -l | grep @ show me that `Marked.app` has a `drwxr-xr-x@  3 gio   staff   102 Aug 10 05:42 Marked.app
` but `> xattr -p com.apple.FinderInfo Marked.app 
` gives me `xattr: Marked.app: No such xattr: com.apple.FinderInfo
`